# Anaconda breaking other stuff that uses Qt

Tags: python, qt

When I setup Anaconda it changes some environment variables and use Qt from its own folder. My other stuff looks for Qt in root directory. I have solved it probably but every time I need to edit .bashrc to switch. Is there any better solution available. I am using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if your are using Ubuntu, there is little reason to use anaconda.

Follow the directions here to uninstall Anaconda: https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install/uninstall

Then install virtualenv. This helps contain your dev environments so you don't cross dependencies & references like you are experiencing. https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/

Alternatively, if you want to keep Anaconda, remove the path listed in your .bashrc at the bottom of the file (I.e. the one created by Anaconda) and set your path to point to the default python location.